# Display Element with Angular 6 (Angular Material) Radio Button and *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to implement that different views are shown on the screen depending on a radio button selected, all this with Angular material, `NgModel`, `NgIf`. But I can not do it. Please help.

HTML code:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="expressType">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let te of typeExpress" [value]="te">
    {{ te }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<ng-template *ngIf="te == 'Component 1'">
  <app-component1></app-component1>
</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="te == 'Component 2'">
  <app-component2></app-component2>
</ng-template>
<ng-template *ngIf="te == 'Component 3'">
  <app-component3></app-component3>
</ng-template>
```

TypeScript code:

```
expressType: string;
typeExpress: string[] = ['Component 1', 'Component 2', 'Component 3'];

radioOptions: FormGroup;
```

Comment: it should be : `*ngIf="expressType === 'Component 1'"` not `te`

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `ng-container` instead of `ng-template` and `expressType` instead of `te` to compare to the `Component n` value.

Try this:

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="expressType">
  <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let te of typeExpress" [value]="te">
    {{ te }}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>

<ng-container *ngIf="expressType === 'Component 1'">
  <app-component1></app-component1>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="expressType === 'Component 2'">
  <app-component2></app-component2>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="expressType === 'Component 3'">
  <app-component3></app-component3>
</ng-container>

<h1>Or with ng-template</h1>

<ng-template [ngIf]="expressType === 'Component 1'">
  <app-component1></app-component1>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="expressType === 'Component 2'">
  <app-component2></app-component2>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="expressType === 'Component 3'">
  <app-component3></app-component3>
</ng-template>

<!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
    enter code here
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-radio-button-to-component-display?file=app/radio-overview-example.html) for your ref.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="expressType">
    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let te of typeExpress" [value]="te">
        {{ te }}
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

**OPTION 1**

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="expressType == 'Component 1'">
    <app-component1></app-component1>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="expressType == 'Component 2'">
    <app-component2></app-component2>
</ng-template>
<ng-template [ngIf]="expressType == 'Component 3'">
    <app-component3></app-component3>
</ng-template>
```

**OPTION 2**

```
<ng-template [ngSwitch]="expressType'">
    <app-component1 *ngSwitchCase="'Component 1'"></app-component1>
    <app-component2 *ngSwitchCase="'Component 2'"></app-component2>
    <app-component3 *ngSwitchCase="'Component 3'"></app-component3>
</ng-template>
```

**OPTION 3**

```
<app-component1 *ngIf="expressType == 'Component 1'"></app-component1>
<app-component2 *ngIf="expressType == 'Component 2'"></app-component2>
<app-component3 *ngIf="expressType == 'Component 3'"></app-component3>
```

> Note that you are comparing **te** instead of the model value **expressType**

Comment: `ng-template` doesn't work with `*ngIf` and would have to be used with `[]` property binding syntax in order to make it work. Could you please update your answer with it.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Updated!

Comment: why you don't :`<app-component *ngIf="..."></app-component>` ?? or better, ngSwitchCase ?